# Are expressions like '+', '=', '>', also considered constants?

Tags: logic

In logic, a constant is a symbol that denotes a particular thing.

It was easy for me to understand that '2' is a constant denoting the number two and that '2+2' is a constant denoting the number obtained by adding two to two. However, in [Alfred Tarski's book Introduction to Logic](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Introduction_to_Logic/vtzCAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA3&printsec=frontcover) he says even '+' is a constant. This made me a little uncomfortable because I usually don't see '+' as the name of a thing. '2' is a name of a thing, but '+' is indicative of an operation that was performed on two things, rather than being a thing in itself.

So my question is are symbols such as '+', '=', '>' etc. also considered constants? How does it make sense to call what they denote as things?

Comment: Logical symbols are logical constants. Sum is a function symbol (a math operation).

Comment: Tarski says right in the passage the sense in which these things are “constant”.

Comment: The "value" of the symbol '$+$' is the function that takes two values and gives the sum of them. What is assigned to this symbol will not change. Therefore it's a constant.

Comment: @md2perpe A similar question: would a sentence that denotes a particular idea, also be a constant?

Comment: I'm not sure how those are normally treated, but I guess that for example the law of the excluded third could be added as a constant in a formal logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in *formal logic*, ‘constants’ are typically symbols we use to denote specific objects. However, Tarski is not doing any formal logic in this particular passage.

In this passage, Tarski is talking about the *mathematical* system of arithmetic, and states that ‘constants’ are symbols that have a fixed meaning:  so when we do arithmetic, we have a specific meaning for symbols like $2$, $+$, $>$, and $=$, as opposed to ‘variables’ like $x$ and $y$.